# How to count number of group by results in Laravel 4.2 without retrieving the whole set of data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Let say I have a table `customer_table` looks like this:

```
customer_name | country | city
--------------------------------------
John          | US      | New York
Paul          | US      | New York
Peter         | US      | Boston
Mary          | UK      | London
Lilian        | UK      | Boston
```

Then, with a model `CustomerTable` set to point to this table, I have a Eloquent query like this:

```
$results = CustomerTable::groupBy('Country', 'City')->get();
```

Where I will get a results that look like this: (it returns as an object, but for better look, I put it in a table)

```
customer_name | country | city
--------------------------------------
John          | US      | New York
Peter         | US      | Boston
Mary          | UK      | London
Lilian        | UK      | Boston
```

I can then find the number of combinations by using `count($results)`. However, I actually only need the number of combination. It is a waste to return all the data. (even if I only return one column, as the number of row is huge in the actual case). I have tried:

```
$results_count = CustomerTable::groupBy('Country', 'City')->count();
```

But this doesn't work. It ways return the number of rows before group by. This is an enhancement on an old project, so I have to use Laravel 4.2. How to get the number of results without retrieving the whole set of data using Eloquent in Laravel 4.2?

Comment: What you are doing is right but there is a bug in that verison of Laravel https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4306

Comment: Oh.... but from the link, it seems that the bug is still there on Laravel 5?

Comment: That's true, it does seem like it. So you would have to work around it, maybe writing raw SQL. Unless there was a performance concern i would just use `->get()->count()`, it does retrieve the dataset, but I would rather have simple code than a more complicated workaround unless the performance hit was noticeable.

Comment: Um.... it is a hard choice for me. While the difference is still not noticeable, it may become noticeable if ours system become popular. The system is not owned by us (we are just paid to build it as a project), so we must decide now.....

Answer (score 0):

Should be  the count on result

```
$results = CustomerTable::groupBy('Country', 'City')->get();
$results_count = $results->count();
```

NB reading you comment  i suggest you

that

```
select count(*) 
from my_table 
group by col1,col2
```

return  the list of the distinct count for each col1,col2 combination ... not the number of the rows  of the query  ..

the number of the rows  othe query is equivalent to

```
     select count(*) from(
        select count(*) 
        from my_table 
        group by col1,col2
     )
```

Comment: Is there way not to do a `get()` first?

Comment: I don't understand your comment ..explain better

Comment: @scaisEdge You should be able to get the count without retrieving the result set.

Comment: The count that you are retrieving  .. is based  on the result set ..  there is not a count of a result set without the result set ..

Comment: Yes, I know it is a count based on a result set, but there should be some way that I don't need to get the whole set to get the count? (i.e. do the count in SQL and only retrieve the number)

Comment: I have update the answer  with a suggestion hope this  is useful